# Will a conductor initially moving in uniform magnetic field continue to move after external force is withdrawn?

Tags: electromagnetism

A conductor(not connected to any external circuit)  is moved in a uniform magnetic field perpendicular to its plane with a constant velocity v until it acquires a steady potential difference between  its ends.

Now suppose the force is withdrawn at the point when it acquires steady P. D, what will happen?

Will the road slow down and eventually stop.? 
          OR
Will it continue to move with same velocity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the magnetic field is perfectly uniform, and the charge distribution in the conductor has reached a steady state, then there is no $\frac{dB}{dt}$ to induce currents in the conductor; absent any external forces not specified in your question, there will be no force on the conductor due to the magnetic field and the conductor can in principle keep moving.

In practice your magnetic field will not be perfectly homogeneous, and the fluctuations will give rise to eddy currents that in turn will have the effect of slowing down the conductor.

Comment: Definitely agree with this. So in the real world it would eventually slow down.